# Is there a hot corner program/addon for Xfce?

Tags: software-recommendation, xfce

Brightside and xfce4-hotcorner-plugin xfdashboard don't exist any more. I'm looking for a hot corner feature for Xubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer works for Xubuntu 20.04 and older versions. For newer versions of Xubuntu that use XFCE 4.16, see the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421901/124466).

---

"**Hot corner**" plugin for '**Xfdashboard**':

The description is here:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/hot-corners-plugin-xfce4/

The deb-files is here:

http://mxrepo.com/mx/repo/pool/main/x/xfce4-hotcorner-plugin/

[image: "Hot corner" plugin for 'Xfdashboard']

Answer (score 1):

The [Xfce4 HotCorner Panel Plugin](https://github.com/christopherkobayashi/xfce4-hotcorner-plugin) is available for XFCE 4.16 (Xubuntu 21.04 and later versions). To install it:

1. Clone the code from GitHub:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/christopherkobayashi/xfce4-hotcorner-plugin --depth=1
   ```
2. Then, compile from source:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
   make && sudo make install
   ```

---

To use the plugin:

1. Right-click on a panel, and select *Panel* → *Add New Items*.
2. Add *HotCorner*.
3. Right-click on the icon of the HotCorner plugin and select *Properties*:

   > [image: screenshot showing the location of the Properties item of the HotCorner plugin]
4. Finally, configure the options for the four hot corners:

   [image: screenshot showing the options for the four hot corners]