# How can I get Icon only "Grouped Modern Window list" on Xubuntu, that I can "pin" in panel too?

Tags: xubuntu, windows-7, taskbar

I want to use **Grouped window list** (Just like in Windows 7 Taskbar).

I am using Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a hot corner program/addon for Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134147/is-there-a-hot-corner-program-addon-for-xfce)

Comment: Could not find a Grouped Window List for xfce https://www.xfce.org/ , the Desktop Environment used by Xubuntu. However, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134147/is-there-a-hot-corner-program-addon-for-xfce explains how to enable Hot Corner functionality.

Comment: @K7AAY, the icon-only grouped window list option is available in the default panel preferences. Of course, it's not as elegant as that in Win7 but then the XFCE team is somewhat smaller than the Redmond one. I don't know why posters club two issues into one question.

Comment: From [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions): "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."

Comment: Well, I took a chance and removed mention of the Hot Corners issue. Now the question may be left open, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

- Right-click on a blank space in the panel
- Open Panel > Panel Preferences
- Click on the Items tab
- Click on Window Buttons and then on the cog-wheel/gear icon
- Make your choices there; the change to Window grouping will be visible in the panel immediately
- Close the Window Buttons window and the Panel window

[image: Xubuntu with Icon only grouped window list]

As the image shows, there are three Firefox windows which are listed when you *left*-click on the Firefox icon. You can right-click on each item for more options. Alternatively, you can right-click on the Firefox icon to see the list as well as available options.

Comment: +1 for a better answer. There is [this somewhat canonical post](https://askubuntu.com/q/233580/37165) for any desktop environment (including Xfce) that was asked in 2012, of which half of all answers are either downvoted or zero-voted for some reason.

Comment: @clearkimura I went there and upvoted a couple. I think the title and body of that question could be edited to remove any mention of "window manager" since I doubt that window managers are involved in any way in this activity.

Comment: I know that. But that's not what I was looking for. I can't pin those windows in the panel.

Comment: You have edited your question just now, several days after posting it, to move the goal posts ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.